# Can't find Android 9.0 (Pie) API 28 ARM System Images

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, arm, android-9.0-pie

Are there anywhere Android 9.0 (Pie) API 28 ARM System images (ARM, not x86 Intel) for AVD Manager? Thanks.

Unofficial? Beta? Alpha? Any?

Comment: arm not released yet, not even for oreo

Comment: Already found it? I am need too!

Comment: @CarlosRocha No.

Comment: it's so hard and very, very dificult